# TCHAR* to LPCSTR - Linker Error

Tags: c++, mingw

I am currently porting some code from Visual Studio to Mingw.This code is from an open source library.I came across this constructor in which a TCHAR* is being passed to to LPCSTR .I simply used the basic Cstyle cast for conversion.In visual Studio I did not need a cast and the application built fine. However I get a linker error in Mingw GCC if I do not place a cast.

This is the constrcutor

```
CAsyncReader::CAsyncReader(
    TCHAR *pName,
    LPUNKNOWN pUnk,
    CAsyncStream *pStream,
    HRESULT *phr)
  : CBaseFilter(
                LPCSTR(pName), // Is this cast ok ?
                pUnk,
                &m_csFilter,
                CLSID_AsyncSample,
                NULL
                ),
    m_OutputPin(
                phr,
                this,
                &m_Io,
                &m_csFilter),
    m_Io(pStream)
{
}
```

And this is the constructor of the parent class CBaseFilter

```
 CBaseFilter(
        __in_opt LPCTSTR pName,    // Object description
        __in_opt LPUNKNOWN pUnk,  // IUnknown of delegating object
        __in CCritSec  *pLock,    // Object who maintains lock
    REFCLSID   clsid,             // The clsid to be used to serialize this filter
        __inout HRESULT   *phr);  // General OLE return code
        }
```

Kindly let me know if this works.

**Update:**

Since the application built fine in VS and is giving me a linker error in Mingw GCC my question is are there any flags that I might be missing in my GCC project or does VS does this implicitly ? Both the projects have UNICODE enabled so I am a totally confused with the linker error. This is the linker error I am getting in Mingw GCC and goes away with the cast (which now I am certain is very WRONG judging from the comments).

```
undefined reference to `CBaseFilter::CBaseFilter(wchar_t const*, IUnknown*, CCritSec*, _GUID const&, long*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is that cast OK?  Simple answer, `No`.

Comment: Could you suggest one ?

Comment: Do *not* cast strings.  Casting strings like that indicate you are doing something wrong.

Comment: No, it is certainly not okay. The nice thing to do would be to not use `TCHAR` unless you plan on supporting really old versions of Windows. Depending on the preprocessor symbols, `TCHAR` expands to different types.

Comment: I do not have the option of changing the constructor parameter type of the base class. What would my options be ?

Comment: Your option is to call a different function that takes the correct string type, or provide the correct string type.

Comment: Actually, that cast is breaking something that wasn't broken.  `TCHAR*` and `LPCTSTR` are compatible, no cast needed.

Comment: My guess is that you compiled the library and your own code with different values of `UNICODE`.  You must fix your code to match the library.

Comment: `I simply used the basic Cstyle cast for conversion.` No a thousand times no.  Casting does *not* perform string conversions.  To convert a string, you actually have to convert it, i.e. call functions to translate from one string type to another.

Comment: @MistyD The bottom line is that you should never cast to another string type.  If in the future you see yourself doing this again, take a step back and carefully inspect the build type used, strings used, etc.  Don't tempt fate and "shut the compiler up" with the cast -- your program will not work correctly, believe me.

Comment: TCHAR and LPTSTR have been obsolete for more than a decade.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie aka "If you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge."

Comment: I'd figure out where and how TCHAR and LPCTSTR are defined.  Also you said both LPCSTR and LPCTSTR above.  Typo?

Comment: What linker error do you get?

Comment: Ill modify the question and update it with more details

Comment: I added more details - along with the linker error

Answer (score 0):

First you need UNICODE and _UNICODE defines. Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Be careful: Some headers use the preprocessor symbol UNICODE, others
>   use _UNICODE with an underscore prefix. Always define both symbols.
>   Visual C++ sets them both by default when you create a new project.

Comment: I have both of these defined